# Placing a child div always bottom of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a html layout wherein the child div should always remain at the bottom of the parent div. The height of the parent div should be 100% by default. Please provide me a solution for the same.

link: https://jsbin.com/pihekufime/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="left">menu</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
    <div class="bottom">index</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
padding:0
margin:0;
}

.header {
 background: #4a90e2;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 width:100%;

 }


.left {

position: fixed;
height: 100%;
top: 100px;
background: #F44336;
width: 20%;

}

.content {

position: relative;
height: 100%;
top: 100px;
left: 20%;
background: #555;
width: 80%;
color:#fff;
min-height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
background: yellow;

}
```

The div with class 'Bottom' should always stay at the bottom of the div with class 'Content' wherein the other divs are fixed

Comment: what you seek is similar to "sticky footer" technique. Google and read on this to apply it to your case

Answer (score 5):

If you set you `.wrapper` to 100% height, the `.content` will also be 100% of the height, and the `.bottom` will be positioned at the bottom of this div. This might not be the behaviour you want, but it is the answer to your question (we dont have info about how the entire thing should work/expand/scroll/align with content)